# How to write code to merge punctuations and phrases using spaCy

Tags: python, python-3.x, nlp, spacy

## What I would like to do

I would like to perse and dependency analysis using spaCy, one of the open-source libraries for natural language processing.

And especially, I hope to know how to write code for the option to merge punctuations and phrases in Python.

## Problem

There are bottons to mearge punctuations and phrases on the displaCy Dependency Vizualizer Web App.
[image]

However, I cannot find the way to write these options when it comes to writing code in the local environment.

The current code returns the following not merged version.
[image]

The sample sentence is from [your dictionary](https://sentence.yourdictionary.com/christmas).

## Current Code

It is from the sample code on [the spaCy official website](https://spacy.io/usage/visualizers).

Please let me know how to fix it to set punctuations and phrases merge options.

```py
import spacy
from spacy import displacy
nlp = spacy.load("en_core_web_sm")

sentence = "On Christmas Eve, we sit in front of the fire and take turns reading Christmas stories."

doc = nlp(sentence)
displacy.render(doc, style="dep")
```

## What I tried to do

There was [one example](https://spacy.io/usage/linguistic-features) for the merge implementation.
However it didn't work when I apply the sentence.

```
import spacy

nlp = spacy.load("en_core_web_sm")
doc = nlp("On Christmas Eve, we sit in front of the fire and take turns reading Christmas stories.")
span = doc[doc[4].left_edge.i : doc[4].right_edge.i+1]
with doc.retokenize() as retokenizer:
    retokenizer.merge(span)
for token in doc:
    print(token.text, token.dep_, token.head.text, token.head.pos_,
            [child for child in token.children])
```

Example Code

```
import spacy
nlp = spacy.load("en_core_web_sm")
doc = nlp("Credit and mortgage account holders must submit their requests")
span = doc[doc[4].left_edge.i : doc[4].right_edge.i+1]
with doc.retokenize() as retokenizer:
    retokenizer.merge(span)
for token in doc:
    print(token.text, token.pos_, token.dep_, token.head.text)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you need to merge noun chunks, check out [the built-in merge_noun_chunks pipeline component](https://spacy.io/api/pipeline-functions). When added to your pipeline using nlp.add_pipe, it will take care of merging the spans automatically.

You can just use the code from the displaCy Dependency Vizualizer:

```
import spacy
nlp = spacy.load("en_core_web_sm")

def merge_phrases(doc):
    with doc.retokenize() as retokenizer:
        for np in list(doc.noun_chunks):
            attrs = {
                "tag": np.root.tag_,
                "lemma": np.root.lemma_,
                "ent_type": np.root.ent_type_,
            }
            retokenizer.merge(np, attrs=attrs)
    return doc

def merge_punct(doc):
    spans = []
    for word in doc[:-1]:
        if word.is_punct or not word.nbor(1).is_punct:
            continue
        start = word.i
        end = word.i + 1
        while end < len(doc) and doc[end].is_punct:
            end += 1
        span = doc[start:end]
        spans.append((span, word.tag_, word.lemma_, word.ent_type_))
    with doc.retokenize() as retokenizer:
        for span, tag, lemma, ent_type in spans:
            attrs = {"tag": tag, "lemma": lemma, "ent_type": ent_type}
            retokenizer.merge(span, attrs=attrs)
    return doc

text = "On Christmas Eve, we sit in front of the fire and take turns reading Christmas stories."

doc = nlp(text)
# Merge noun phrases into one token.
doc = merge_phrases(doc)
# Attach punctuation to tokens
doc = merge_punct(doc)

for token in doc:
    print(token.text, token.pos_, token.dep_, token.head.text)
```